# Express keeping connection open?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I'm using node js, express and postgresql as backend.
This is the approach I used to make a rest API:

```
exports.schema = function (inputs, res) {
  var query = knex('schema')
    .orderBy('sch_title', 'asc')
    .select();

  query.exec(function (err, schemas) {
    if(err){
      var response = {
        message: 'Something went wrong when trying to fetch schemas',
        thrownErr: err
      };
      console.error(response);
      res.send(500, response);
    }
    if(schemas.length === 0){
      var message = 'No schemas was found';
      console.error(message);
      res.send(400, message);
      return;
    }
    res.send(200, schemas);
  });
};
```

It works but after a while postgres logs an error and it's no longer working:

```
sorry, too man clients already
```

Do I need a close each request somehow? Could not find any about this in the express docs. What can be wrong?

This error only occurs on production server. Not on developing machine.

**Update**
The app only brakes in one 'module'. The rest of the app works fine. So it's only some queries that gives the error.

Comment: looks like the db conection isnt closed when it finish the query. not about express.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757549/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-fatal-sorry-too-many-clients-already any use?

Comment: This is definitely a problem with your postgres and not with express. Can you post the relevant parts of the DB code?

Comment: @jeremy, well I'm just creating tables with columns. No funny things going on there. Isn't there any "close" command I need to use in my REST-api?

Comment: You app should have only one connect call and one connection to postgres, it shouldn't ever need to be closed during typical operation

Comment: What version of the knex library are you using? Looks like some persistent client connection bugs were fixed recently: http://knexjs.org/#changelog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just keep one connection open for your whole app. The [docs shows an example](http://knexjs.org/#Initialize) how to do this.

This code goes in your `app.js`...

```
var Knex  = require('knex');
Knex.knex = Knex.initialize({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    // your connection config
  }
});
```

And when you want to query in your controllers/middlewares...

```
var knex = require('knex').knex;

exports.schema = function (req, res) {
    var query = knex('schema')
        .orderBy('sch_title', 'asc')
        .select();
    // more code...
};
```

If you place `Knex.initialize` inside an `app.use` or `app.VERB`, it gets called repeatedly for each request thus you'll end up connecting to PG multiple times.

For most cases, you don't need to do an open+query+close for every HTTP request.

Comment: Where would you suggest doing a knex.destroy() in this scenario? Or is it sufficient that if the server goes down, the connection is probably destroyed?

Comment: The connection would just expire but if you want a more graceful solution, you can listen to a `SIGTERM` event using Node.JS process. Something like this: https://gist.github.com/hyubs/2dbc0265b8079948c92b