# Sorry too many clients are already logged

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee

there's someone who knows this error " Sorry too many clients are already logged" ,even if i increase number of connection pool size in my persistence like that.i still have it
Any help please this error blocks my progress !!!

Comment: this question already have answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757549/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-fatal-sorry-too-many-clients-already

Comment: i solve it i forgot to close my session :)

Comment: i saw it my friend but i had an other problem anyway thank you

Answer (score 0):

That error points at a connection leak.  If you create new connections without releasing all of them, you'll eventually run out!

Have a look at [`pg_activity`](https://github.com/julmon/pg_activity/).  It's a "top" for Postgres and can often quickly identify the source of the leak.  Another option is [to set Postgres to more verbose logging](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-logging.html) and analyse the log file.

Comment: thank you i solve it  , i forgot to close my session i'm using Hibernate :)