# Kill postgre connection in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, connection

How can I kill all postgre connections using rails console? I am getting this:

```
PG::ConnectionBad
FATAL: sorry, too many clients already FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

Rails.root: C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/Work/Extreme Blue Summer Internship/extreme-blue

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/pos
```

The thing is I don't want to drop the database, but just to kill all the connections to it? Any help will be kindly appreciated!

tgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'

Comment: Is there somewhere in your code where you are making connections? Perhaps the connections are being left open perpetually?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757549/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-fatal-sorry-too-many-clients-already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a PostgreSQL superuser, you can use the function `pg_terminate_backend` to kill a session. You can get a list of backend process IDs from the `pg_stat_activity` view.

So the query could look like this:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

To be less disruptive, you could add `AND state = 'idle'`.

Make sure your application does not connect as superuser, then there will always be `superuser_reserved_connections` (default 3) connections left that can be used by a superuser.

All that said, your application should really not exceed a maximum number of connections. If you can't guarantee that, use a connection pooler like pgBouncer.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz for your answer. Is rails automatically closing connections as I don't remember to have written any loops which should let me active connections

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `rails console` to kill Postgres processes.

You should restart Postgres however you started it (either from the command-line or e.g. from the PostgresApp application) and it will clear the current connections.

As a side note - you shouldn't be exceeding the number of connections Postgres can offer inside a Rails app. You'd either need a *lot* of concurrent users, or some really problematic loop somewhere.